# How to auto-increment a field in a access table based on the sum of a field in other table

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a tracker for each customer's debt. Right now, let's say, I created 2 tables in Ms. Access.

First table is the customer table with 4 fields: ***CustID, Cust_Name, Cust_Phone, and Cust_Active_Debt***. Cust_Active_Debt is basically the sum of all of the money that Customer owed me from all of his invoice that hasn't been fully paid yet.

The second table, let's say, the debt invoice table. I would always created this debt invoice whenever my customer ask me to pay the invoice later so they get to keep the product first then pay me later. The debt invoice table is consisted of fields: ***InvoiceID, invoiceDate, CustID, Total_Debt***(which is basically the sum price of the product that they bought).

The field ***Total_Debt*** from the debt invoice table will be incremented to the Customer table in ***Cust_Active_Debt*** so the ***Cust_Active_Debt*** field in the customer table will be added by the ***Total_Debt*** everytime I created a debt invoice for him

So far, I can create an Access Form for the Debt Invoice table. But my problem is how can I incremented the ***Total_Debt*** field to the ***Cust_Active_Debt*** field in the customer table every time I make a debt invoice for a customer so I have the total debt that is still active for each of my customer from all of the debt invoice that is made for their name/custID?

Comment: Total_Debt should be calculated when needed, not saved in table.

Comment: `MS-Access` strongly recommend not to save calculated value. If still need to save then in your case you have to use `DSum()` function.

Comment: Ohhh... I see. So what would be your recommendation if I still want to increment a customer's total active debt everytime a debt invoice is made under his name?

Comment: Don't!  Just look up Access and Invoice online.  Or more generally Access and Total query or Access and Group by.  The tutorials and youtube videos are bountiful.  When you want the customers  active debt it is a matter of a few mouse clicks to make and run a query that gives you customer and active debt.  Or better yet make a report that takes less mouse clicks and is formatted for printing.  If you must have a table just save the query table.  Updating  the active debt every time is very doable but much harder and raises the chance of data corruption significantly.

Comment: Okay thats actually quite helpful, will try to look it up in youtube tutorials thanks a lot mate! :)